# Can I use node or node-gcm to recieve upstream messages from an android device?

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

All of the examples I see are pushing notifications from the server to the client. How do I contact the server from the client and how would the path look?

Normal http requests can be matched using app.get('path',callback). Is this same matcher used to match gcm requests?

Answer (score 1):

The GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP) is meant to send messages back and forth from Server to Client and from Client to server. It provides a persistent, asynchronous, bidirectional connection to Google servers. The connection can be used to send and receive messages between your server and your users' GCM-connected devices.

JSON messages are send across the network for both Upstream and Downstream messaging. Every message sent to CCS receives either an Acknowledgement or a No Acknowledgement response. Messages that haven't received one of these responses are considered pending. If the pending message count reaches 100, the 3rd-party app server should stop sending new messages and wait for CCS to acknowledge some of the existing pending messages.

For more details visit this official [Google document](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html).

To look for an app implementation where you can send messages both upstream and downstream you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/)

Hope that Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Found something that might be useful. The example node.js implement xmpp server that in turn receives upstream message from device to server. Hope this helps out.

[**link**](https://gist.github.com/jamesvnz/6756208)